# Htmlentities();  и html_entity_decode();  Не выводит результат

Tags: php

Проблема состоит в том,  что я обрабатываю строки этими функциями и хочу добавить в базу вывод но он не вносится в БД. Делаю для того чтобы можна было на сайте отобразить код, но при этом чтобы он не исполнялся. Спасибо за помощь!
Вот например:

```
<?php 
$p="<a href='http://www.site.com/'>
djfkjshbfjhjsfbsjhdf</a>
<img src='test.png'> ";
echo $a=htmlentities($p);
echo html_entity_decode($a);
?>
```

Comment: @Vitaliisss, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Что выводится в браузер?

Comment: Может у Вас просто ошибка синтаксиса из-за переносов внутри кавычек?  http://ideone.com/qhY2fJ  
 Работает как должно'

Answer (score 1):

```
$p="<a href='http://www.site.com/'>
djfkjshbfjhjsfbsjhdf</a>
<img src='test.png'> ";
echo htmlspecialchars($p);
```

Это обычный вывод обработанной переменной в поток. Чтобы записать её в базу данных, необходимо гуглить.

Comment: это не чего не дало, изменения в БД не внеслись... Може ещё кто значет в чем проблема?